# Inno Setup update application by backup database, uninstall RDBMS, reinstall latest version RDBMS and restore database

Tags: firebird

I have application that use Firebird RDBMS version 2.5 that I need to update to use Firebird RDBMS version 4.0.

I need to perform, during installation of update, those steps:

1. Backup existing database (like a command line: FirebirdDir\gbak -user xxx -password yyy dbSource dbDestination);
2. Uninstall Firebird 2.5;
3. Install Firebird 4.0;
4. Restore existing database (like a command line: FirebirdDir\gbak -rep -user xxx -password yyy dbDestination dbSource);

but I don't know how to do those steps.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks the suggestions received I wrote this code in the code section of the innosetup script:

```
[code]
function VersioneFirebirdServerCheck(Versione: string; var AFirebirdDir: string): Boolean;
var
  Key, Istanza: string;
  success: boolean;
begin
  Key := 'SOFTWARE\Firebird Project\Firebird Server\Instances';
  if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM64, Key, 'DefaultInstance', Istanza) or 
     RegQueryStringValue(HKLM32, Key, 'DefaultInstance', Istanza) then
    Result := Pos(Versione, Istanza) > 0;
  if Result then
    AFirebirdDir := Istanza;
end;

function InitializeSetup(): boolean; 
  var AFirebirdDir: string; 
begin
 if (VersionFirebirdServerCheck('_2_5', AFirebirdDir)) then
   begin 
     MsgBox('Next I Backup actual Database and uninstall Firebird 2.5', mbInformation, MB_OK); 
     if Exec (AFirebirdDir + 'gbak.exe', '-user xxx - password yyy dbSource dbDestination', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then 
       if Exec (AFirebirdDir + 'unins000.exe', '', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then ... 
   end 
  else Result := True; 
end;
```

Comment: I recommend you ask on [firebird-support](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support). Given this is not about programming, it is off-topic here. That said, what is unclear about those steps? Before asking on firebird-support, think a bit longer on what you really want to ask.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Actually it is a programming question. He asks how to call gbak and installer from InnoSetup, which may be done by section "Run" or PascalScript.

Comment: @user13964273 I find that debatable, the OP first has to work out how to do this by hand, then try to script it. If they then run into a problem, then they have to ask a specific question, not handwave the problem and expect us to solve it. Also, they only tagged [tag:firebird], so if they needed support with installer scripting, they less likely to get it.

Comment: I am not asking for you to write the code for me but for a suggestion on how/what to document about it.
In the meantime, I discovered that in the [code] section of innosetup I can invoke external programs using the Exec function of PascalScript which I did not know.

Comment: So I started to write my code:
[code]
function InitializeSetup(): boolean;
var
  AFirebirdDir: string;
begin
  if (VersionFirebirdServerCheck('_2_5', AFirebirdDir)) then
    begin
      MsgBox('Next I Backup actual Database and uninstall Firebird 2.5', mbInformation, MB_OK);
      if Exec (AFirebirdDir + 'gbak.exe', '-user xxx - password yyy dbSource dbDestination', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
        if Exec (AFirebirdDir + 'unins000.exe', '', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
          ...
    end
   else Result := True;
end;

Comment: Please [edit] details into your question, don't add them in the comments (especially code becomes pretty much an unreadable mess as you can see).

Comment: I can't edit, maybe it has been too long to edit my comment, now I only see "Delete" and not also "Edit". Sorry.
How can I post the code to make it more readable?

Comment: You need to [edit] the question, not the comment. You can always edit your question (either with this [edit] link, or the edit link directly below your question).